# Twitter Bootstrap Assets Call Using Laravel Framework

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

i have simple question.

I developing a new php project using laravel framework. I just want to import the assets/ folder content which is css and js from twitter bootstrap. I have place the files in my public/ folder so the path like this `public/assets/css` or `public/assets/js`

I have place this code in my view page:

```
    <link href="{{ url('assets/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ url('assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ url('assets/css/pages/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but the page is still unstyled. When i see the page source the link wasn't generated properly like the source below

```
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/pages/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

any ideas?

**update**

still not working, i have update the script into

```
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/pages/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but still not rendered in my browser.

**UPDATE 2**

here is the full source code for my `auth.blade.php` views file in `app\views` folder

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>User Login - Invoinizer. Online Collaboration Invoice Generator</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> 

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css') }}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/pages/signin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="navbar-inner">

            <div class="container">

                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

                <a class="brand" href="index">Invoinizer.</a>

                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">

                        <li class="">                       
                            <a href="signup" class="">
                                Don't have an account?
                            </a>

                        </li>

                        <li class="">                       
                            <a href="index" class="">
                                <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
                                Back to Homepage
                            </a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->    

            </div> <!-- /container -->

        </div> <!-- /navbar-inner -->

    </div> <!-- /navbar -->



    <div class="account-container">

        <div class="content clearfix">

            <form action="#" method="post">

                <h1>Member Login</h1>       

                <div class="login-fields">

                    <p>Please provide your details</p>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="login username-field" />
                    </div> <!-- /field -->

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="login password-field"/>
                    </div> <!-- /password -->

                </div> <!-- /login-fields -->

                <div class="login-actions">
                    <span class="login-checkbox">
                        <input id="Field" name="Field" type="checkbox" class="field login-checkbox" value="First Choice" tabindex="4" />
                        <label class="choice" for="Field">Keep me signed in</label>
                    </span>

                    <button class="button btn btn-success btn-large">Sign In</button>

                </div> <!-- .actions -->
            </form>

        </div> <!-- /content -->

    </div> <!-- /account-container -->

    <div class="login-extra">
        <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
    </div> <!-- /login-extra -->


    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/signin.js') }}"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have tried using `{{HTML::style('../css/bootstrap.min.css')}}` instead of `<link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template to be a `.blade.php` as it sounds like it is not being recognized as a blade template.

Try

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**UPDATE:**

based on your comment try creating a simple route like this:

```
Route::get('Auth',function() {
   return View::make('auth');
});
```

then visit `Auth` and see that it has rendered correctly

**UPDATE 2:**

Removed `assets\` from the path

Comment: then when i call the file using the routes still not working. file is renamed like this: `auth.blade.php`

Comment: @randytan se my try you need `URL::asset` so it knows what class to call

Comment: Hi @AbstractChaos; i have submit the full page syntax. please check update 2

Comment: hi there, it's working now. is there any incompatibilities when i place the sub folders? anyway thanks for helping me. :)

Comment: @randytan not that i'm aware of. I have however moved my assets out of public folder as I prefer to contain a site with its own folder and have the assets at top level

Comment: then how to call the assets file out of public folder?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50709/discussion-between-abstractchaos-and-randytan)